# Figure out a FK creation error on Mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I would need double eyes to see why I can't create the following Foreign Key.

```
ALTER TABLE `DEFAULTS_OPTIONS`
ADD CONSTRAINT `DEFAULTS_OPTIONS_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`univers_code`) REFERENCES `UNIVERSES` (`code`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Here is the description of the tables involucrated:

```
CREATE TABLE `DEFAULTS_OPTIONS` (
`country_code` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`univers_code` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`element_code` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`option_code` varchar(8) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`element_category` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`country_code`,`univers_code`,`element_code`,`option_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `UNIVERSES` (
`country_code` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`code` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`image` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`order` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`country_code`,`code`),
CONSTRAINT `UNIVERSES_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country_code`) REFERENCES `COUNTRY` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'DEV_DEV.#sql-aa2_2e1' (errno: 150)
```

Does anybody see my error?

Thanks in advance for taking a look.

**EDIT:**

Naktibalda adviced me to examine the result of

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

to help to figure out the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It fails because you don't have an index for UNIVERSES.code field,
your PRIMARY KEY is not good for that because code isn't the first field in PK.

If you want to refer to a combination of 2 fields,
use

```
ALTER TABLE `DEFAULTS_OPTIONS`
ADD CONSTRAINT `DEFAULTS_OPTIONS_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`country_code`, `univers_code`) REFERENCES `UNIVERSES` (`country_code`, `code`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 1):

To define *simple, uncombined* foreign keys, parent column must also be indexed.

It seems `UNIVERSES.code` column is not indexed.

**Change it as follows**:

```
ALTER TABLE UNIVERSES ADD KEY ( code );
```

Now you can add foreign key to `DEFAULTS_OPTIONS` table on `UNIVERSES.code` column.